# Control on Page Navigations in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac, xamarin.forms

I have a value on screen1 which keeps on incrementing from 0 and when I navigate to screen2 it has to stop. When I navigate back it has to start incrementing from the stopped value.

How do I catch the current page change in Xamarin C# like wise OnAppearing and OnDisappearing for the app

Thanks!

Comment: What's supposed to happen if the user navigates away, and then presses e.g. the home button and exits the app? What value do you start incrementing from next time the first page is shown? Does it matter if the app was just suspended, or actually shut down?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use NavigationPage?
If yes, you can use its Pushed and Popped events.
If no, please describe how exactly you implement your navigation.